# Heroku deployment fails during Bundle Install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, gemfile

When pushing my app Rails3 to Heroku, it gets rejected with:

> Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
>   sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

but when I run `ruby -c Gemfile` I get `Syntax OK`.

Any tips?

Edit:
source code can be found here: https://github.com/tubedude/portfolio_tracker
I'm using ruby 2.1.0 and Rails 3.2.17

Comment: Can you past your Gemfile? What stack are you deploying to and what Ruby version?

Comment: I don't know if you saw it, but I've added the link to the project git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same issue on two of our apps. It turned out that a recent stack upgrade caused one of Heroku config variables to throw this error. One of our passwords had a double quote which caused the`Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string` Error. I suggest checking your Heroku config variables for this issue.

To check this run `heroku config` in your console

Comment: Awesome! I'd never look at the system variables. My `SECRET_TOKEN` had a double quote right at the end of it. Thank you.

Comment: FYI, I had a custom config variable WITHOUT any quotes at all that still caused this issue. It was an option passed to the ruby interpreter. Heroku must have changed the way they're sanitizing the string.