# NoMethodError: undefined method `web_console' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration while deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Any ideas how to fix it? Website is working fine locally.

My error is: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'web_console' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration`

I tried to google for solution, but I didn't find right answer. I'm getting this error while deployiong to Heroku.

```
Counting objects: 134, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (131/131), done.
Writing objects: 100% (134/134), 151.11 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 134 (delta 72), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.4
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Using rake 11.2.2
remote:        Using i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Using json 1.8.3
remote:        Using minitest 5.9.0
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Using builder 3.2.2
remote:        Using erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
remote:        Using pkg-config 1.1.7
remote:        Using rack 1.6.4
remote:        Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
remote:        Using arel 6.0.3
remote:        Using acts_as_votable 0.10.0
remote:        Using execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Using bcrypt 3.1.11
remote:        Using sass 3.4.22
remote:        Using cancancan 1.15.0
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Using thor 0.19.1
remote:        Using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
remote:        Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Using devise-i18n 1.1.0
remote:        Using tilt 2.0.5
remote:        Using sexp_processor 4.7.0
remote:        Using multi_json 1.12.1
remote:        Using mimemagic 0.3.1
remote:        Using nested_form 0.3.2
remote:        Using pg 0.18.4
remote:        Installing decent_exposure 2.3.3
remote:        Installing puma 3.6.0 with native extensions
remote:        Installing request_store 1.3.1
remote:        Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
remote:        Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
remote:        Using remotipart 1.2.1
remote:        Using safe_yaml 1.0.4
remote:        Using will_paginate 3.1.0
remote:        Using rdoc 4.2.2
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Using mime-types 3.1
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.6.8
remote:        Using rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Using warden 1.2.6
remote:        Using autoprefixer-rails 6.3.6.1
remote:        Using uglifier 3.0.0
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using sprockets 3.6.0
remote:        Using haml 4.0.7
remote:        Using ruby_parser 3.8.2
remote:        Installing decent_decoration 0.0.6
remote:        Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
remote:        Using will_paginate-bootstrap 1.0.1
remote:        Using sdoc 0.4.1
remote:        Using activesupport 4.2.6
remote:        Using mail 2.6.4
remote:        Installing faker 1.6.6
remote:        Using loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Using rack-pjax 0.8.0
remote:        Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.6
remote:        Using html2haml 2.0.0
remote:        Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Using globalid 0.3.6
remote:        Using activemodel 4.2.6
remote:        Using climate_control 0.0.3
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.5.0
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
remote:        Using activejob 4.2.6
remote:        Using activerecord 4.2.6
remote:        Using cocaine 0.5.8
remote:        Using actionview 4.2.6
remote:        Using paperclip 5.0.0
remote:        Using actionpack 4.2.6
remote:        Using actionmailer 4.2.6
remote:        Using active_link_to 1.0.3
remote:        Using railties 4.2.6
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.0.4
remote:        Using kaminari 0.17.0
remote:        Using simple_form 3.2.1
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.1.1
remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.1.1
remote:        Using responders 2.2.0
remote:        Using font-awesome-rails 4.6.3.1
remote:        Using haml-rails 0.9.0
remote:        Using jquery-ui-rails 5.0.5
remote:        Using rails 4.2.6
remote:        Using sass-rails 5.0.4
remote:        Using turbolinks 2.5.3
remote:        Using devise 4.1.1
remote:        Using commontator 4.11.1
remote:        Using rails_admin 0.8.1
remote:        Using jquery-turbolinks 2.1.0
remote:        Installing draper 2.1.0
remote:        Bundle complete! 43 Gemfile dependencies, 93 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (6.43s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     NoMethodError: undefined method `web_console' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007f04617e1b40>
remote:  !     /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/config/application.rb:25:in `<class:Application>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:Angipl>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/Rakefile:4:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:686:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `block in run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `load'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `<main>'
remote:  !
remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:102:in `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)
remote: ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote: and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote: rake aborted!
remote: NoMethodError: undefined method `web_console' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007f04617e1b40>
remote: /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing'
remote: /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/config/application.rb:25:in `<class:Application>'
remote: /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:Angipl>'
remote: /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/Rakefile:4:in `require'
remote: /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
remote: /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:686:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote: /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `block in run'
remote: /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote: /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
remote: /tmp/build_a0a3715eb7863d440ca59f388461f927/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote: vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `load'
remote: vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `<main>'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:746:in `rake'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:131:in `log'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:71:in `block in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:     from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:70:in `run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:767:in `allow_git'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:98:in `block in compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:     from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:88:in `compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:49:in `block in compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:     from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:47:in `compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:38:in `block in compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:     from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:37:in `compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:41:in `block in compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:     from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:40:in `compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/compile:16:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:131:in `log'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/compile:15:in `block in <main>'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `block in trace'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:     from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `trace'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/compile:11:in `<main>'
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to angipl.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/angipl.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/angipl.git'
```

My gemfile looks like that:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.4'
end
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development


gem 'haml', '~> 4.0.5'
gem "haml-rails", "~> 0.9"
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
gem 'devise'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'active_link_to'
gem 'commontator', '~> 4.11.1'
gem 'devise-i18n'
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.10.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'
gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10'
gem "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"
gem 'draper', '~> 2.1'
gem 'decent_exposure', '~> 2.3', '>= 2.3.3'
gem 'decent_decoration', '~> 0.0.6'
gem 'faker', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.3'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.4'
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem "better_errors"
  gem 'capybara'
end

group :production do
  gem 'puma'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.1'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'simplecov', :require => false
end
```

Comment: did you run bundle exec rake -P

Comment: Yes, I did. I didn't help.

Answer (score 6):

if you are running in production mode, try to specific it as:

```
RACK_ENV=production bundle exec ...
```

Answer (score 6):

I had run into this because I had included config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx' in my application.rb. Move it to development.rb.

Answer (score 2):

I guess maybe you run your app in production mode?, you should add `gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'` in group production.

Comment: I tried to do it this way, but I didn't help. I stucked with this.

Comment: I did that, but i think it maybe can make the app less secure in production, trying to find other solution, but is nice as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is my solution to fix this problem.

1. `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`
2. `git add .`
3. `git commit -m`
4. `git push heroku master`

I found right answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017128/heroku-deployment-fails-during-bundle-install)

Answer (score 1):

This happeded with me when i ran

```
bundle install --without development test ci
```

I fixed it with

```
bundle install --with development test ci
```